# Replace href in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to transform this:

```
http://link_brochure/1/2 OR link_brochure/1/2
```

into this:

```
class="show-brochure" href="http://localhost/main/brochure/1/2"
```

But I'm a rookie when it comes about regular expressions... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You had the code quoted correctly the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$str=preg_replace(
    '{(?:http://)?link_brochure/(\d+)/(\d+)}', 
    'class="show-brochure" href="http://localhost/main/brochure/$1/$2"', 
    $str);
```

Edit: updated following question edit (Thanks Peter).

Comment: Question has changed slightly - need to add `(?:http://)?` to make that part optional, and add `localhost/` to the replacement side.

Probably also worth explaining that the `$1` and `$2` refer to the two captured `(\d+)` bits, so the link will work regardless of what numbers are there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use str_replace to replace 'main/' with 'link_', then 'a ' with 'a class="show-brochure"'.

On iPad, so can't be bothered to type code, but look up str_replace, and you'll get the idea!

Comment: Hi, Rich! 
I asked the wrong question initially.
But thanks for your answer :)